# How to combine two Monte Carlo algorithms into a Las Vegas one?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic-randomness

Consider a decision problem $D$ with corresponding Monte Carlo algorithms $X$ and $Y$ satisfying the following properties:

- If $D(s)$ is true, then $X$ returns true with probability $p$ and false otherwise. If $D(s)$ is false, then $X$ always returns false (in particular, if $X$ returns true, it is always correct).
- If $D(s)$ is true, then $Y$ always returns true. if $D(s)$ is false, then $Y$ returns false with probability $q$ and true otherwise (in particular, if $Y$ returns false, it is always correct).

Can we use $X$ and $Y$ to construct a Las Vegas algorithm solving $D$?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what your original post means. I proposed an edit with my best guess for what you meant in your original question, but I'd like to receive confirmation it is what you meant before giving an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to be correct, we'd better only use processes we can be confident are correct. In particular, there's really only one thing we *can* do.

```
def L(s):
  loop:
    if X(s) returns true, return true
    if Y(s) returns false, return false
```

Clearly this is correct provided that it terminates by the definitions of $X$ and $Y$. We now argue that this algorithm has finite expected runtime. Let $T_X(n)$ and $T_Y(n)$. The expected runtime of $L$ is simply $T_X(n)+T_Y(n)$ times the expected number of iterations of this program. To compute that, we note that the probability of the program not halting on any given iteration is at most $r=\max\{1-p,1-q\}$, as we either need $X$ to incorrectly return false or $Y$ to incorrectly return true to not halt. In particular, the number of iterations is a geometric random variable with parameter $r$ and thus expected value $\tfrac 1r$, which is finite.